# MediaWiki page: Linking to an anchor inside collapsed div?

Tags: html, mediawiki

On my MediaWiki page I'm trying to create an anchor link to a collapsed div so that when I click it, it jumps to that div and expands it automatically.  I can anchor to the heading ("How do I...") fine and it jumps to it but doesn't expand the collapsed div when I click on the link.

```
<div class="mw-collapsible mw-collapsed" style="width: 750px;border: 1px solid;
     border-radius: 10px;padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;margin: 1px">
====How do I...====
<div class="mw-collapsible-content">
This is how you do blah blah blah...<br \>
</div>
</div>
```

I've tried putting an anchor inside the collapsed content div and linking to it, but this had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could try specifying a visible state using the [`:active` pseudo selector](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/active/). The problems with that are: 1) browser support isn't universal; and 2) it relies on window.location to set the `active` state; if you simply click on a heading to expand, you'll have to use a different solution in any case.

A more general solution is that you'll have to remove the 'mw-collapsed' class on click using JavaScript. Your MW installation's ability to support custom JS may vary, however.

Comment: Well, your suggestion sent me down the rabbit hole of CSS (since I can't use JS on this Mediawiki page).  And I *could* use the :active pseudo class, if it worked in IE.  I can get :hover to work fine in IE, but not :active. :active works if I try it in Chrome though.  I appreciate your assistance.  Looks like I'll have to go a different direction that what I'd hoped.

Answer (score 0):

It's been awhile since I posted this question, and I did come up with a way to do what I wanted and have it be completely HTML and CSS based (No Javascript).  It's a bit hacky, but it works with all 4 browsers I tested it with (IE, Chrome, Firefox and Opera) and also on iOS and Android mobile devices.

First, I have this CSS on my MediaWiki:Common.css page.

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
from { opacity: 0 }
  to { opacity: 1 }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
from { opacity: 0 }
  to { opacity: 1 }
}

.answer {
height:0;
width:auto;
margin: 1px;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0 18px;
-webkit-transition: all 1.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 1.5s ease;
transition: all 1.5s ease;
}

.linkshow:target * .answer {
display: block;
-webkit-animation: fadeIn 1.5s;
animation: fadeIn 1.5s;
height: auto;
padding: 24px 18px;
border: 1px solid;
border-radius: 10px;
}

.linkhide:target * .answer {display: none;}
```

and in my HTML I have these div structures.  Each structure has a different id based on if it's the "show" div or the "hide" div.  I also have 2 links to "hide", one at the top and one at the bottom, if the items in-between are numerous enough so that the top "hide" can get scrolled off the screen.

```
<div class="linkshow" id="SUBJECT1linkshow">
<div class="linkhide" id="SUBJECT1linkhide">
<div>[[#SUBJECT1linkshow|How do I Blah, Blah, Blah, etc.?]]</div>
<div class="answer">
<div style="float: right;">[[#SUBJECT1linkhide|Hide]]</div>
<br \>
To do blah, blah, blah...:

*Do this step.<br \>
*Do this next.<br \>
*Once you've done that, do this.<br \>
*etc. etc. etc..<br \>

<div style="float: right;">[[#SUBJECT1linkhide|Hide]]</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="linkshow" id="SUBJECT2linkshow">
<div class="linkhide" id="SUBJECT2linkhide">
<div>[[#SUBJECT2linkshow|Can I change my Blah, Blah, Blah, etc.?]]</div>
<div class="answer">
<div style="float: right;">[[#SUBJECT2linkhide|Hide]]</div>
<br \>
To change your blah, blah, blah...:

*Do this step.<br \>
*Do this next.<br \>
*Click the "Edit" button.[[File:My_Screenshot.png|none]]<br \>

'''''Note:  Before these changes will take effect, you must et. etc. [[#SUBJECT3linkshow|Do that thing]].'''''<br \>

<div style="float: right;">[[#SUBJECT2linkhide|Hide]]</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

You can have whatever you want inside the inner div.  Bullet lists, ordered lists, images, or even targets to other "answers" on the same page.

When the page is first shown, all of the answers will be collapsed and you'll only see a list of questions.  Clicking on one will trigger the transition to the expanded state with a nice border around the answer.  Clicking "Hide" will collapse, or clicking on another question will collapse the currently open answer and expand the new one.

Hope this helps someone.